# Array in Where clause

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, where-clause

How I can insert a array into where clause? This is the first query to get the ID:

```
$query = "SELECT id FROM #_categories WHERE alias = 'agenda'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
   while($linha = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
   $vNome = $linha['id']; 
}
```

Now the second query to get the final result:

```
$query = "SELECT introtext FROM $tabela WHERE catid IN ($vNome) <> ''";
```

And the result is:

```
SELECT introtext FROM #_content WHERE catid IN (36) <> ''
```

Why I can't put all IDs in the clause IN?

PS: Sorry for the bad english, is not my native language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$vNome=array();
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
  while($linha = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  $vNome[] = $linha['id']; 
}
```

Then the sql:

```
$query = "SELECT introtext FROM $tabela WHERE catid IN (".implode(",",$vNome).")";
```

Answer (score 0):

Change loop to this

```
$vNome = array();
$i = 0;
while($linha = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
   $vNome[$i] = $linha['id']; 
   $i++;
}
```

Then use this $vNome array.

Answer (score 0):

`IN` is a SQL keyword. You cannot pass raw PHP arrays to SQL.

You have to first read the data into an array and then expand the array:

```
$query = "SELECT id FROM #_categories WHERE alias = 'agenda'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$vNome = array();
while($linha = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $vNome[] = $linha['id']; // don't forget the [] to put it into an array, else the value will be scalar!
}
$query = "SELECT introtext FROM $tabela WHERE catid IN (".implode(",", $vNome).")";
```

Answer (score 0):

$vNome isn't an array. In your while clause, you're just overwriting the variable.  Before the while, initialize the variable

```
$vNome = array();
```

Then inside of the while, change it to

```
$vNome[] = $linha['id'];
```

Now when it comes to the second query, you can't just pass in the array, you'll have to implode it.

```
$vNomeStr = implode (',',$vNome);
```

Then you can use $vNomeStr inside of your query. As long as it's numbers, this will work fine, otherwise you'll have to also encapsulate each item in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing a nested select statement like this:

```
SELECT introtext 
FROM $tabela 
WHERE catid 
IN (
    SELECT id 
    FROM #_categories 
    WHERE alias = 'agenda'
);
```

There may be more efficient ways, but this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Imploding the array to a comma separated string will give you the opportunity to use the "1,2,3" string in the `IN (...)` operator